# Rigorously prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2) (\sqrt3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

As stated, I want to argue that the identity holds i.e. the smallest field containing $\sqrt2$, $\sqrt3$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is indeed the smallest field containing $\sqrt3$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$.

Comment: Perhaps you should *first* tell us what is **your** definition of $\;\Bbb F(a,b)\;$ , with $\;a,b\;$ some elements (in some algebraic extension of $\;\Bbb F\;$ if you prefer) .

Comment: I suggest that you prove $F(a,b)=F(a)(b)$. No need to specialize to $\mathbb{Q}$ or square roots. Your definition of $F(a,b)$ is wrong, it is not the smallest field containing $F,a,b$ - such a field does not exist. It is the smallest *subfield* of some *fixed algebraic extension* (for example, some algebraic closure of $F$) containing $F,a,b$.

Comment: **My** definition: $\mathbb{F}(a, b)$ is the SMALLEST field containing $\mathbb{F}$ together with $a, b$ in alg.ext. of $\mathbb{F}$. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show that one of these fields is contained in the other?

Comment: You could also look at the form of a general element of one and convert it to the form of a general element of the other. For instance, rewrite
$$
a + b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3 + d\sqrt6 \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)
$$
to an element of the form
$$
a' + b'\sqrt2 + (c' + d'\sqrt2)\sqrt3 \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt2)(\sqrt3)
$$
to show that one is contained in the other.

Comment: Yes I know the fact of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3) = \left \{ a+b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3 + d\sqrt6 : a, b, c, d\in \mathbb{Q} \right \}$. But could you please give some hints on the proof of this identity following the definition?

Comment: There is no need to fiddle around with roots ...

Answer (score 5):

There is *no* smallest field containing a field $F$ and elements $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$. This is also not the correct definition of $F(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$. Here is the proper definition:

Let $L/F$ be an extension and $a_1,\dotsc,a_n \in L$. Then $F(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$ is the smallest subfield of $L$ which contains $F$ and the elements $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$. That means:

$F(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$ is a subfield of $L$ containing $F,a_1,\dotsc,a_n$. If $E$ is another subfield of $L$ containing $F,a_1,\dotsc,a_n$, then $F(a_1,\dotsc,a_n) \subseteq E$.

This definition is quite abstract, but you can also check that the elements of $F(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$ are just fractions of polynomial expressions in $L$ with variables from $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$and coefficients from $F$. So an example would be $\dfrac{a_1 a_2^3 - u}{ a_3 - a_1}$ (if $u \in F$ and $a_1 \neq a_3$).

**Claim.** If $L/F$ is a field extension and $a,b \in L$, then $F(a)(b)=F(a,b)$ as subfields of $L$.

*Proof.*

- $F(a)(b)$ contains $F(a)$. Thus, it contains $F$ and $a$. It also contains $b$. Thus, $F(a,b) \subseteq F(a)(b)$.
- $F(a,b)$ contains $F$ and $a$. Thus, $F(a) \subseteq F(a,b)$. But $F(a,b)$ also contains $b$. Thus, $F(a)(b) \subseteq F(a,b)$. $\checkmark$

In your example, $L=\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$ perhaps), $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $n=2$, $a_1=\sqrt{2}$, $a_2 = \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already proved that almost in the same way, still thanks a lot. btw my definition in the comment may be equivalent to yours, note that I didn't write down L explicitly.

Comment: One more question, is it necessary for L to be ALGEBRAIC?

Comment: No, it's not. In the comment I wrote that just because the elements were algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

Put a=√2+√3 ; we note K=Q(√2) , L=Q(√3) , M=Q(a) and show K=M=L.
x∈M↔x=r_4
 a^4+r_3 a^3+r_2 a^2+r_1 a+r_0  ;〖  r〗_i∈Q
The calculation gives x=A√6+B√2+C√3+D where A, B, C, D are rational. Therefore x=(A√3+B) √2+(C√3+D)∈L(√2) ;  x=(A√2+C) √3+(B√2+D)∈K(√3) .
Then K=M=L since clearly K and L are contained in M.

Comment: Please use MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)(\sqrt3) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)(\sqrt2)$?

Comment: 1)Thanks very, very much for your link, Spenser.
2)Yes ,RagingBoson, this is true which is clear from my comment (it is even true in other instances much more general than for (2,3).)